# Ubuntu live on external hard drive

Tags: external-hdd

Is it possible to partition external hard drive into 2 partition and put Ubuntu live image on one of the partitions? And how can I boot from this partition?

Comment: see if these pages help: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1535864 and http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1572336

Comment: Do you want to run from external hd, or just the main disk? Get confused with the generality in "to partition hard drive".

Comment: external drive, my bad

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://askubuntu.com/questions/102163/iso-live-session-from-an-external-hard-drive

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for slow response.

## Yes.

I am actually running my Ubuntu installation this way. You need to perform the installation with but a few changes:

Follow [How do I install Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/6328/how-do-i-install-ubuntu/152902#comment201080_152902) up to the "Installation Type" prompt. Here, you must select "Something Else".

Find your external hard disk in the partition list, and click its partition. Click Edit. Change the size to leave some empty room, removing at least 20000 MB as a bare minimum(I recommend at least 100000MB).

Click OK, and allow it to apply changes. Now, click in the free space created, and click Add. Add an `Ext4` partition with the default space available, and set the mount point to `/`.

On the bottom, click in the dropdown for bootloader installation, and select your external hard disk.

### **Ensure that it isn't your internal hard disk!**

Click install, and continue with the instructions.

To boot, ensure your hard disk is plugged in, and press the key for the boot menu(usually <kbd>F10</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd>, or <kbd>F12</kbd>), and select your hard disk to boot from, and proceed booting as normal.

Comment: I'm not sure this is the same thing the OP is talking about. It seems like he wants to use a partition on an external disk as a liveUSB of sorts, not necessarily install Ubuntu on it.