# Install from harddrive

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, ms-dos

I want to put Lubuntu on some old Laptops. It does not have a cd, dvd, usb ports, card reader, nor pxe boot. I've read around and cant find any similar situations. (sorry if I missed it!)

Years ago I took the hard drive and connected it directly to my xp machine, formatted the drive as dos bootable, copied xp cd to the drive, put the drive back into the laptop. Now I could boot to dos, and simply run setup. all good. 
but it was rather slow!! and has since been corrupted.

Is it possible to do similar with Lubuntu?
can I copy a (live?) cd to the hard drive and boot to it?

Thanks.

Comment: Please add specifications of the laptop to your question.

Comment: If a laptop doesn't have a USB port it probably is too old even for Lubuntu. How much RAM do the old laptops have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of is to take the hard drive out of the laptop that you want Lubuntu on, install it into another machine that has CD/USB boot capability.  Disconnect ANY other hard drives from the installing system, install as normal, then replace drive into the laptop.  As long as you installed the version for the correct architecture (x86 vs amd64) you should be good to go.

If you do not have the capability to install the hard drive into another machine, but can connect it externally via a USB adapter, you can usually install to a USB attached disk as well.  Another option is to create a Virtual Hard Disk image and install Lubuntu through a virtual machine, then use a utility to write the image to the physical disk.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

Two links which explain well how you can do :

[Ubuntu live on external hard drive](https://askubuntu.com/questions/152997/ubuntu-live-on-external-hard-drive)
and
http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2013/10/23/how-to-install-ubuntu-13-10-on-an-external-hard-drive/

It talks about Ubuntu, but it's similar with Lubuntu...